# Extract text from pdf to c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm looking for a way to extract text from a pdf and use it i a program.  I've done some research on the net and got a few libraries working. These were not freeware; however, en bumbed on there limits.

So i'm looking for a free library. I thought of ITextSharp but i have no idea to get started.
Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: Check out the documentation and resources: - http://api.itextpdf.com/
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365986/documentation-for-itextsharp

Comment: Please note that iTextSharp is not a freeware either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like should work for you. You have to watch it - they change function names all the time with iTextSharp releases, which is a bit annoying - Lol

```
public static string GetPDFText(String pdfPath)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath); 

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();  

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) 
        output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: allright, nice! Still a question tough: is there a problem if there are images in the pdf, or will he just read over them?

Comment: This should be fine if there are images contained within the document. To extract images you would need to check each pdfobject in the objects collection. this will only extract text :)

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp is open source but the licensing model changed after version 4.1.6. The old license was much less strict while the new one requires payment if you use it commercially and don't want to release your source code. This may or may not affect you.

Here's the most basic version of text extraction using the 5.1.2.0 version:

```
//Full path to the file to read
string fileToRead = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), @"file1.pdf");
//Bind a PdfReader to our file
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileToRead);
//Extract all of the text from the first page
string allPage1Text = iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1);
//That's it!
Console.Write(allPage1Text);
```